# EC2 Windows Server Instance should always have display on

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, remote-desktop

I have a JAVA program running using Sikuli (GUI testing framework that does image search on the screen, simulates mouse and keyboard actions) that works fine locally.

The same JAVA program runs fine in a Windows EC2 instance as long as I am connecting to that EC2 instance via Remote Desktop.

If I turn off the remote desktop, the EC2 Windows server immediately turns off its display. The JAVA program runs "screenlessly" and throws some errors because the screen is not available for the program to perform image search etc.

Is there a way to make the EC2 Windows instance always run with a screen display even if no one is connecting to it via RDP? Or maybe is there a way to simulate a RDP connection to a Windows EC2 instance?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run Sikuli in headless mode. Headless mode allows GUI softwares to work on a device without a graphical user interface.

Here is link to explore further :

[Headless Sikuli with VNC](http://jesg.github.io/testing/2014/07/04/headless-sikuli.html)